# python dict,list has same instance for all classes

Tags: python, list, class, dictionary, instance

I am working on python 2.7 from last 3 months and I am really surprised after noticing this today.

For the following snippet of code

```
class Example:
    children = {}

instance1 = Example()
instance1.children['instance1_child1'] = 'Instance 1 child 1'

instance2 = Example()
instance2.children['instance2_child1'] = 'Instance 2 child 1'
for key, value in instance2.children.items():
    print key + ' -> ' + value
```

why the output is

```
instance1_child1 -> Instance 1 child 1
instance2_child1 -> Instance 2 child 1
```

It seems like there is only one instance of dict() for all the objects I am creating. I checked with list[] also and they are also behaving in the same manner.

I can't understand this behavior of python and what is the logic behind it. Is this some kind of design flaw or am I doing something wrong and deserves to quit programming?

Comment: Yes its a static member of the `Example` class. If you wanted it to be a per instance member it would need to be attached to self i.e. define it in the `__init__` method as `self.children`.

Comment: You have used class variable. You must use instance variable for your case. Read it here: [Class and Instance Variables](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables)

Comment: Just to complicate things further, if you have inserted this sentence in your code: `Example.children['bar'] = 'foo'` then you would have got this additional output: `bar -> foo`

Comment: @julivico The link was helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By creating these variables outside the context of a member function, you have unwittingly created a *class variable*.

Class variables are accessible to every class instance and can be accessed directly from the class itself without instantiating.

```
Example.children == Example().children
>>> True
```

Think the equivalent of a global variable defined within a class, and you have your answer.

---

To correct this, simply place them within the context of `__init__`.

```
class Example(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.children = {}
```

Now `children` is bound to the class *instance*, and not the class itself.   Such is the power of `self`.

Comment: would be useful to add an example of code that would correctly create the instance variable

Comment: @JulienSpronck I was in the process of doing so when you commented :)

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `children` as class variable instead of instance variable. If you change it to instance variable instead it will behave as you would expect:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = {}

instance1 = Example()
instance1.children['instance1_child1'] = 'Instance 1 child 1'

instance2 = Example()
instance2.children['instance2_child1'] = 'Instance 2 child 1'
for key, value in instance2.children.items():
    print key + ' -> ' + value

# Output: instance2_child1 -> Instance 2 child 1
```